# onSubmit function not running in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to do something with the user input to search from the wikipedia api. onSumit is not running the searchQuery function. It will only run if I call it in the onSubmit, but then it doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
const SearchForm = () => {
      const [search, setSearch] = useState(0);
      const searchField = (event) => {
        setSearch(event.target.value);
      };
    
      const searchQuery = async () => {
        const params = {
          action: "query",
          format: "json",
          list: "search",
          srsearch: search,
        };
    
        const url = new URL(
          "https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/"
        );
    
        for (let param in params) {
          url.searchParams.append(param, params[param]);
        }
    
        const searchData = await fetch(url);
        const data = await searchData.json();
        document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
        console.log(data);
      };
      searchQuery();
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={searchQuery}>
            <input
              type='search'
              placeholder='search wikipedia'
              onChange={searchField}
            ></input>
            <input type='submit' value='search'></input>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to prevent the default form submission behavior.

The `onSubmit` callback receives the event of type `FormEvent`. Use that event object to prevent the default value i.e. `e.preventDefault()`

```
 const searchQuery = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // add this
    const params = {
      action: "query",
      format: "json",
      list: "search",
      srsearch: search,
    };
    ......
```